# Why does Hedy Lamarr get credit for inventing wifi?

Tags: history, wifi

A few weeks ago I saw a Facebook post giving credit for inventing wifi to Hedy Lamarr. I had only a vague idea on the creation of wifi, but I did remember it involved IEEE, so I decided to look it up. It was clearly invented, maybe not quite the right word since it appears more of a protocol, by the IEE that Hedy Lamarr was not part of.

I asked about it, and got an answer that she gets credit for it because she invented frequency hopping. I checked this, and found first, wifi doesn't use frequency hopping. Second, frequency hopping was being used by Germans in 1915. This would make it quite impressive for Hedy Lamarr to have invented it since she would have been 1 year old at the time.

I checked what Hedy Lamarr did do, and it appears she patented, with another person, a device to sync frequency hopping devices using a mechanical drum system. As far as I have found, this technology was never used in any device, and I can't find any evidence someone built off this technology in developing frequency hopping technologies that became prevalent. So, despite the ingenuity of this, it didn't actually contribute to any advancement of frequency hopping or communication encryption.

However, in the last few weeks since seeing this post, I've seen probably 8 or 9 other posts claiming the same thing, and if you type who invented wifi into Google, it will answer that Hedy Lamarr did.

So, other than did I just miss something profound here and am completely wrong (if so I'd greatly appreciate a sourced walk through of how her contributions led to wifi), why is she suddenly getting credit for inventing a technology that she apparently had nothing to do with (I've never heard anyone give her credit for wifi until about a month ago, but now it's everywhere).

Oddthinking, in a very roundabout way, asked me to confirm this is a recent phenomenon, so I looked into it. I checked Google search trends for Hedy Lamarr wifi, and got these results for all time and 5 years.

[image: google search frequency, all time]

[image: google search frequency, 5 years]

As you can see, there is considerable evidence for this being a recent phenomenon, and also apparently one that in the last few years is potentially showing temporal autocorreclation with spiking at this time of year, so yes, there is evidence that this is suddenly appearing.

Edit 2:

Apparently why questions aren't great questions, so let's try this.

1. Is there a plausible explanation to give Hedy Lamarr credit for inventing wifi
2. did any of Hedy Lamarr's inventions or discovers directly lead to wifi or a technology used in wifi
3. what caused the recent association of Hedy Lamar and wifi
4. what causes the apparent spikes in interest in Hedy Lamarr and wifi in March and April in the last several years

Comment: A "why" question is about motivation (and psychology and sociology) and we can't answer that. Turn your question into one about facts. Point to a notable claim and ask if it is true.

Comment: Also, look into the [Baader-Meinhoff phenomenon](https://www.onboardmeetings.com/blog/baader-meinhof-phenomenon). Lamarr has been heralded as an inventor for years and years.

Comment: Evidence: Here is a [ten year old question on the same subject](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/did-hedy-lamarr-and-george-antheil-invent-frequency-hopping-or-spread-spectrum-c).

Comment: @Oddthinking Any idea why this is called the “Baader-Meinhof phenomenon”? I can’t make out any connection.

Comment: @gnasher729, ask Google for "Baader-Meinhof Phenomenon".

Comment: @gnasher729: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_illusion): "The name "Baader–Meinhof phenomenon" was coined in 1994 by Terry Mullen in a letter to the St. Paul Pioneer Press. The letter describes how, after mentioning the name of the German terrorist group Baader–Meinhof once, he kept noticing it. "

Comment: @Oddthinking there is almost certainly a recent association and spike in interest in Hedy Lamarr and wifi, see edits

Comment: There is that connection made, you've clearly demonstrated in your post. As to the "why" - that's not what we do here. We could try and challenge the veracity of the claim or that the claim was made at all - the ten year old question that Oddthinking comments about gets rid of the former, and the evidence provided in your post gets rid of the latter. Little more we can do unless you edit with an alternative question.

Comment: Q1 is vague; I could come up with many plausible explanations. Q2 is a duplicate. Q3 isn't a notable claim (it isn't widely believed). Q4 isn't a notable claim (it isn't widely believed).